# Get a row in data.frame as a vector where each element is a string

Tags: r

I have issues getting the output I want from a data.frame. The structure of the data is the following:

```
head(test)

    A  T  L   B  E  X   D
4  no no no yes no no yes
7  no no no  no no no  no
11 no no no  no no no  no
12 no no no yes no no yes
17 no no no  no no no  no
27 no no no  no no no  no
```

The output I get:

```
test[1,]
   A  T  L   B  E  X   D
4 no no no yes no no yes
```

The output I want:

```
[1] "no"  "no"  "no"  "yes" "no"  "no"  "yes"
```

Or simply, the output I want is a vector where each element is a string value of that column in the `df`. I could do a for loop or some stupid thing like that, but I belive there should be a much simpler way that I am missing.

I have tried:

```
as.character(test[1,])
[1] "1" "1" "1" "2" "1" "1" "2"
```

Not sure what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unlist` and then `as.character`

```
as.character(unlist(test[1, ]))
#[1] "no"  "no"  "no"  "yes" "no"  "no"  "yes"
```

`test[1, ]` is still a dataframe and applying `as.character` on data frame doesn't work. We use `unlist` to make dataframe to vector and then use `as.character` to convert it into character.

**data**

```
test <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "no", class = "factor"), 
T = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "no", class = "factor"), 
L = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "no", class = "factor"), 
B = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", 
"yes"), class = "factor"), E = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "no", class = "factor"), X = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "no", class = "factor"), D = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("4", "7", "11", "12", "17", "27"))
```